# How to do dynamic object creation and method invocation in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, clr, invocation

How does the code looks that would create an object of class:

```
string myClass = "MyClass";
```

Of the above type, and then call

```
string myMethod = "MyMethod";
```

On that object?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.  Are you trying to dynamically create the type, ie, dynamically define a class, as well as dynamically call a method on that type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Use [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx) to get the type object.
- Use [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) to create an instance.
- Use [`Type.GetMethod(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) to retrieve a method.
- Use [`MethodBase.Invoke(object, object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke.aspx) to invoke the method on the object

Example, but with no error checking:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Foo
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Type type = Type.GetType("Foo.MyClass");
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
            method.Invoke(instance, null);
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In MyClass.MyMethod");
        }
    }
}
```

Each step needs careful checking - you may not find the type, it may not have a parameterless constructor, you may not find the method, you may invoke it with the wrong argument types.

One thing to note: Type.GetType(string) needs the assembly-qualified name of the type unless it's in the currently executing assembly or mscorlib.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a library which simplifies dynamic object creation and invocation using .NET you can download the library and the code in google code: [Late Binding Helper](http://code.google.com/p/latebindinghelper/)
In the project you will find a [Wiki page with the usage](http://code.google.com/p/latebindinghelper/wiki/Usage), or you can also check this [article in CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LateBindingHelper.aspx)

Using my library, your example will look like this:

```
IOperationInvoker myClass = BindingFactory.CreateObjectBinding("MyClassAssembly", "MyClass");
myClass.Method("MyMethod").Invoke();
```

Or even shorter:

```
BindingFactory.CreateObjectBinding("MyClassAssembly", "MyClass")
     .Method("MyMethod")
     .Invoke();
```

It uses a fluent interface, and truly simplifies this kind of operations. I hope you could find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes an object with a public constructor and a public method that returns some value but takes no parameters.

```
var object = Activator.CreateInstance( "MyClass" );
var result = object.GetType().GetMethod( "MyMethod" ).Invoke( object, null );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your class is in your executing assembly, your constructor and your method is parameterless.

```
Type clazz = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("MyClass");

System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo ci = clazz.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
object instance = ci.Invoke(null); /* Send parameters instead of null here */

System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = clazz.GetMethod("MyMethod");
mi.Invoke(instance, null); /* Send parameters instead of null here */
```