# Dynamically generate XAML objects

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, c#-3.0

I have a Silverlight app that displays a number of "pages".  Each page is a different XAML file with different code behind.  The pages are numbered sequentially as follows: page_1, page_2, page_3, ..., Page_n.  The pages are not static and will be dynamically generated.

Since I don't know the total number of pages, I have to load each page at runtime using the Dynamic keyword.  My code is as follows as is working perfectly:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Pages.Page_" + (index).ToString(), true);
dynamic newPage = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

My problem is that I've just learned that the app must be Silverlight 3 and, as a result, it will not be able to use the dynamic type.  I've tried changing "dynamic" to "object" but I need to be able to access the XAML on each page and manipulate the XAML.  If all I needed was to access properties and methods, I'd be able to follow the solution for creating dynamic objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483215/how-to-do-dynamic-object-creation-and-method-invocation-in-net-3-5).

How can I dynamically create each page and still be able to access the XAML?

Comment: The first answer is correct, but it sounds like your site should be data driven instead. A contrived page numbering system usually indicates a design problem. If you let us know more about the actual business problem you are trying to solve, we might be able to offer a better solution. Cheers

Comment: The page numbering system certainly is contrived but, in this situation, it is very much by design.  The pages are generated from a Microsoft Word document and then inserted into a Silverlight app and can change at any time.  In this case, the page numbers do make a lot of sense.  Regardless, in this specific situation, the "pages" will live only in a static Silverlight app that will let users scroll through the content.  The numbering system doesn't matter so long as it is consequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that each page is a UserControl.  If this is the case then you're pretty much already there.  Instead of creating dynamic objects, create a bunch of UserControl objects.

Change your code to this:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Pages.Page_" + (index).ToString(), true);
UserControl newPage = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```