# Is there a way to return data from a database call as an general object rather than a specified type, without creating a new class

Tags: c#, sql, database, object

I have a function that is trying to return a list of all transactions from the database. To do this it needs to retrieve all the data from TransactionItems, and then join that to the data retrieved from Transactions. I want to be able to do this without creating any new classes (if at all possible)

```cs
  public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetTransactionBySaleId(int id)
  {
      var query = ("SELECT t.*, ti.* " +
         "FROM Transactions t " +
         "INNER JOIN TransactionItems ti ON t.SaleId = ti.SaleId " +
         "WHERE t.SaleId = @Id");

      // Parameterisation to prevent injection attacks
      var idParam = new SqlParameter("Id", id);

      return await DatabaseConnection.Instance.ExecuteQueryAsync<object>(query, idParam);
  }
```

My ExecuteQueryAsync method:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters) where T : new()
 {
     using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

     await connection.OpenAsync();

     var resultList = new List<T>();

     using var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

     // Add parameters to the command if any
     if (parameters != null)
     {
         command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
     }

     using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
     
     while (await reader.ReadAsync())
     {
         var obj = new T();
         MapData(reader, obj);
         resultList.Add(obj);
     }
     
     return resultList;

 }
```

My issue is that the return type is currently object, and all this does is return empty objects for each entry in the tables. I first had it set to return Transactions but this didn't display the data from TransactionItems.

Data in my Transactions table:
[Transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcMRf.png)

Data in my TransactionItems tale:
[TransactionItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9MmI.png)

I'm still relatively inexperienced, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why not use a SqlDataReader? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-7.0

Comment: I cant use SqlDataReader because the number of rows will be different for both tables

Comment: Not sure I understand how that would prevent the use of SqlDataReader, if you can provide some sample data or expand on your example that may help.  Thanks.

Comment: I have added images of the data in my tables. Like I said, if i change object to Transaction on the line DatabaseConnection.Instance.ExecuteQueryAsync<object> then it only returns SaleId, CustomerId, DateAndTime and TotalCost.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Can you refactor your code to make use of a SqlDataReader rather than an Task<IEnumerable<object>>, i.e.: Task<SqlDataReader> - essentially, the SqlDataReader would allow you to iterate over the result set and would give you access to all columns in the result of your SQL join statement.

Comment: SqlDataReader is proving very difficult to implement. Customer extensions are required among other complex things that for this use, are simply not worth doing. If there is any other way you can think to get my code working then feel free to suggest, but if not I might leave it

Comment: One other option is to dynamically create an object from the SQL data - see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862349/dynamically-create-object-from-sql-data.

Comment: I have found a fix. I created a new class that has attributes for each column of the table. Then in my code i have 

return await DatabaseConnection.Instance.ExecuteQueryAsync<CombinedTransaction>(query, idParam);

Comment: Yes - of course that will work, but your original question stated, "I want to be able to do this without creating any new classes".   In any case, glad you found a solution.